# Pointers Help C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm confused. How does secondvalue = 20? In the comments is what I think is going on, am I missing something somewhere?

```
int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
int *p1, *p2;

p1 = &firstvalue; //assign the address of firstvalue to p1
p2 = &secondvalue; //assign... secondvalue to p2
*p1 = 10; //assign 10 to the value pointed by p1 (firstvalue now = 10)
*p2 = *p1; //assign the value pointed by p1 to the value pointed by p2
           //secondvalue = 10, firstvalue = 10
p1 = p2; //assign the address of secondvalue to the address of firstvalue
         //address of firstvalue = address of secondvalue
*p1 = 20; //assign 20 to the value pointed by p1 (firstvalue = 20)
```

The output should be
    firstvalue = 10 and secondvalue = 20 but from my understanding firstvalue = 20 and secondvalue = 10. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: did you run the code? what are the result?

Comment: Your comments at p1 = p2 are incorrect. This statement assigns the addess of secondValue to p1, not to the address of firstvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p1 = p2; //assign the address of secondvalue to the address of firstvalue
```

Here you set the `p1` pointer to point at what `p2` points to. So `p1` is now pointing at `secondvalue`.

Nothing is pointing at `firstvalue` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:
You assign FV = 5, SV = 15, P1 = adress of FV, P2 = adress of SV.

1. You set P1 value (FV) to 10. You have FV = 10, SV = 15.
2. You set P2 value to P1 (you set SV = FV). So FV = 10, SV = 10.
3. You set P1 to P2 (so P1 points to SV).
4. You set P1 value to 20 (you set SV = 20). So FV = 10, SV = 20.

That's outcome.
firstValue = 10, secondValue = 20

Answer (score 0):

The value of firstValue = 10 and secondValue = 20 is true,
In the 7th line of code (i.e, p1=p2) the pointer p1 is now pointing to the address of p2 (which is actually the address of secondvalue). Now, when changing the value of *p1 to 20, it changes the value of secendValue.